# iOS- Fetch Google spreadsheet Data Without Sign In

Tags: ios, google-sheets-api

Is there any way to Access google spreadsheet Api Without Google SignIn In Swift? I have gone through the Google Document but Didi not get any solution https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios

Answer (score 0):

No. Performing API calls like reading and writing to cells in Sheets v4 require authorization. You can see that [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) has authorization scopes. More of that in [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#top_of_page).